# Issues in VBA ".Apply"

Tags: excel, vba, apply

Trying to make a dynamic sort macro, works on first column, then I get an error when I try to run on new column (trying to sort each column A-Z without changing the order of the other columns).

```
Sub SortCell()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set StartCell = ActiveCell

ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    ActiveCell, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange ActiveCell.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

End With
MsgBox "Action complete.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you describe the error you obtained, please? "Issues in VBA .apply" is not that explicit unfortunately

Comment: @UncleBenBen you're right, but my money is on a useless "1004: Application-defined error" message ;-)

Comment: You say that you want to sort the individual columns one at a time without affecting the other columns but defining `LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` then using to set a range with `.SetRange ActiveCell.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))` is not operating on a single column.

Comment: It is the 1004 error, sorry!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to work with the Sort code version that recording uses. This is very verbose and 'remembers' parameter values from previous operations. There is a much more concise syntax available that is just as effective.

```
dim c as long

with activesheet
    for c=1 to .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
        if .cells(.rows.count, c).end(xlup).row >1 then
            with .columns(c).Cells
                .Sort Key1:=.cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            end with
        end if
    next c
end with
```

Comment: So, it works on the first few columns on my sheet, sometimes it works on more than others, I haven't figured out the reason yet. How would I make sure it works for the entire sheet? This is my first time trying to write code for VBA.

Comment: Sorry, but you've left too many questions unanswered for me to provide a definitive response. Maybe catch up on the comment section in your question and edit your question to include the error number and what line of your code it actually occurs on.